# Conda Skeleton Fails

Tags: conda, python-wheel

I published a sample python package on [Pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pythonpackagetemplate/) using wheel. I would like to publish the package on my Conda channel using [this](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tutorials/build-pkgs-skeleton.html) tutorial.

However when I run:
`conda skeleton pypi rutgerhofstepythonpackage` I get the following error:

```
Warning, the following versions were found for rutgerhofstepythonpackage
0.0.1
0.0.2
0.1.1
Using 0.1.1
Use --version to specify a different version.

Leaving build/test directories:
  Work:  /opt/anaconda3/conda-bld/skeleton_1523284768777/work
  Test:  /opt/anaconda3/conda-bld/skeleton_1523284768777/test_tmp
Leaving build/test environments:
  Test: source activate  /opt/anaconda3/conda-bld/skeleton_1523284768777/_test_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placeho
  Build:        source activate  /opt/anaconda3/conda-bld/skeleton_1523284768777/_build_env


Error: No source urls found for rutgerhofstepythonpackage
```

Comment: I can't find that package on PyPI: https://pypi.org/search/?q=rutgerhofste-python-package although you linked to it... very strange

Comment: there is clearly something weird going on with my package. Included a screenshot

Answer (score 4):

Conda Skeleton Requires a source distribution. Uploading a wheel to pypi is not sufficient.

In addition to a build distribution
`python setup.py bdist_wheel --universal`
create a source distribution
`python setup.py sdist`

before uploading to PyPi. I figured this out while trying to manually create the meta.yaml file using this [tutorial](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/build-packages/define-metadata.html#source-section)

Comment: In hindsight, that error message makes perfect sense... it cannot find the URL for the source code.